# Save Material in game by user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i Have color picker in my game to customize character clothes by user in game.
how can i save this changes ?
i've try this way but doesn't work and i don't know why :

```
public Material[] ShirtColorMat;

Renderer renderer;
int PantSaver;

void Start()
{
    renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    PantSaver = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Saver");
}

public void _000000()     // i use this on button 
{
    renderer.material = ShirtColorMat[0];
    
    Save();
}
 void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saver", PantSaver);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the `PantSaver` value.

It should probably rather be

```
public void _000000()
{
    PantSaver = 0;
    renderer.material = ShirtColorMat[PantSaver];
    
    Save();
}
 void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saver", PantSaver);
}
```

---

In general a property might be of good use here:

```
private int _pantSaver;
private int PantSaver
{
    get => _pantSaver;
    set
    {
        _pantSaver = value;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saver", value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        renderer.material = ShirtColorMat[value];
    }
}
```

This way everytime you assign a new value to `PantSaver` it is automatically saved and the renderer updated.

So then you would only need to do

```
public void _000000()
{
    PantSaver = 0;
}
```

Finally please rename `_000000` to something more meaningful like e.g. `ResetPant` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might in `Save()` want to say `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saver", ShirtColorMat[0]);` instead. What you have in "PantSaver" [is not a reference but a value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html). This means that with the above code you are currently first getting the value "Saver" and then setting the same value again.

The [PlayerPrefs.SetInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html)'s first string parameter is the key you save it to and later can get it from.

Comment: `ShirtColorMat[0]` will be a `Material` .. not an `int` ... How do you want to save a `Material` as `int`?

Comment: Could grab the color value from the material and save it as a string, or as multiple ints.